# Can no longer pass children to react-instantsearch connected refinement list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algolia, react-instantsearch

During a React & Typescript version upgrade and subsequent dependency update, it seems that my implementation of using `connectRefinementList` from `react-instantsearch-dom` is now complaining about having children as part of it's usage, whereas there were none before.

```
TS2322: Type '{ children: string; attribute: string; limit: number; searchable: true; showMore: true; }' 
is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<RefinementListExposed
, any, any>> & Readonly<...>'.   Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & 
IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<RefinementListExposed, any, any>> & Readonly<...>'.
```

My usage is as such:

**CustomRefinementList**

```
const RefinementList: React.FC<React.PropsWithChildren<any>> = (props) => {
    // other stuff here

    return (
        <div>{props.children}</div>
    )
};

const CustomRefinementList = connectRefinementList(RefinementList);

...

// Error highlights this CustomRefinementList element
<CustomRefinementList attribute="some-attr" limit={5} searchable showMore>
    Some children here
</CustomRefinementList>
```

Is there something I'm missing here, or has the functionality just gone weird since updating from `6.22.0` to `6.39.1`?

Looking into `connectRefinementList`:

```
export function connectRefinementList(
    stateless: React.FunctionComponent<RefinementListProvided>,
): React.ComponentClass<RefinementListExposed>;
```

With its used types being defined as

```
export interface RefinementListProvided {

    refine: (value: string[]) => any;
    createURL: (...args: any[]) => any;
    currentRefinement: string[];
    items: Array<Hit<{ count: number; isRefined: boolean; label: string; value: string[] }>>;
    searchForItems: (...args: any[]) => any;
    isFromSearch: boolean;
    canRefine: boolean;
}

export interface RefinementListExposed {
    attribute: string;
    searchable?: boolean | undefined;
    operator?: 'or' | 'and' | undefined;
    showMore?: boolean | undefined;
    limit?: number | undefined;
    showMoreLimit?: number | undefined;
    defaultRefinement?: string[] | undefined;
    facetOrdering?: boolean | undefined;
    transformItems?: ((...args: any[]) => any) | undefined;
}
```

Of course, none of these have `children` defined... But I'm not entirely sure why it wouldn't accept me giving children to it?

Comment: It's not clear what part of the code is generating an error.

Comment: @super have included the line `<div>{props.children}</div>` to make it more clear now.

Comment: Ok. One would think it's probably smarter to just tell us... ?

Comment: Either way... it looks a lot like an error coming from mixing versions of react types. The `children` props was removed from `React.FC` when they upgraded to version 18. An educated guess is that an old lib that expects <18 types are getting >18 types.

Comment: @super that's kind of the issue... I'm not entirely sure. Of course none of the dependency types accept `children` as such, but it did work before the version update...

Comment: What do you mean you're not sure? The error will tell you.

Comment: @super a I misunderstood what you meant, it highlights the `CustomRefinementList` element used.

Comment: @super with regards to your `React.FC` removing the implicit `children` pop in `18`, that's why I included the `React.PropsWithChildren<>` in the type. Or are you arguing that we should do away with this also? Or is your point that the lib's `RefinementListProvided` not going to allow child usage as it's a `React.FunctionComponent` which no longer has the implicit children prop included.

Comment: Yes, the last one would be my guess. It can also be some dependency that has a lower version or react types in combination with an unspecific enought dependency in some package.json that leads to the wrong one being resolved. I've had similar issues. You could always try to purge `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` and reinstall everything.